# Does the WITH on OpenJson has something to do with the WITH CTE?

Tags: sql-server

Learning OpenJson on sql-server 130, I come to the WITH clause

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql

searching deeper, I come to the WITH common_table_expression

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

While it has help me to learn about the CTE to understand better how OpenJson works, and the syntasis is similar, I am not sure whether both WITHs are related, or it is just a causality the usage of same word

On the other hand, if not related, I would have expected another name for the with clause, like "AS", "STRUCTURED_AS", "WITHSTRUCTURE", "CASTED", "INSHAPEOF", "LIKE" etc...

```
OpenJson ( jsonExpresion [, path] ) [STRUCTURED_AS ({colName type ...}...)
```

Comment: They are not related. Plus using `WITH` keyword in different context could cause ambiguity, so you are enforced to end statement before CTE with semicolon

Comment: @lad2025 thanks !!,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think `OPENJSON` WITH is similar to [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017). This makes sense when [some queries can be helped to achieve better performance when WITH is used.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/05/29/use-with-clause-in-openjson-to-improve-parsing-performance/):

```
-- this requires two JSON parses
SELECT count(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.model') = 'Golf'

-- this requires one JSON parse only
SELECT count(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH(model nvarchar(20) )
WHERE model = 'Golf'
```

In this case, WITH behaves similarly to a hint (it is not required, but helps the engine to perform better).

As a side note, CTE can be used along with JSON WITH clause and it might lead to better readability. E.g.:

```
;with Comp as (
    select * from OPENJSON (
        (   SELECT BulkColumn
            FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'companies.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j)
        )  
WITH (   
    CompanyId INT '$.companyId' ,  
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(128) '$.companyName',
    CountryName NVARCHAR(128) '$.countryName',
    FoundedDate DATETIME '$.foundedDate'
 ))
SELECT *
FROM Comp
```